# Validate if JSON returns ["message", "Not Found"] in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, parsing

I'm using an API to get a JSON response. There's a variable URL that a user specifies. So if they have a spelling error sometimes it won't find the JSON file. I'm looking to do a simple conditional to see when the JSON returns ["message", "Not Found"] so I can either skip it or validate when it's successful to use the returned information.

Here's my current code

```
url = "https://api.something.com/users/#{CGI.escape(@user.external.username)}/yes?type=owner"
something_yes_test = HTTParty.get(url)
something_yes_test_info_response = something_yes_test.parsed_response
```

Answer (score 0):

With a friends help, the returned message was coming through json and had a specific result "message" so we can just do

```
if something_yes-test_info_response["message"]
  means it is broken
else
  it is not broken
```